# Ignore initial Transition for first mount React-Spring

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-spring

I have a react component which needs a transition for for in and out.
But on the first mount it should not use an entry animation.
I use a simple fade in fade out. the initial keyword should deactivate the initial transition for the first mount. But it does not work. The following transitions work as aspected.

I tried to find a solution but most of the topics were outdated or did not work for me.
Maybe I am missunderstanding something since I am pretty new to React & React-Spring.

```
<Transition
    native
    items={this.state.showComponent}
    initial={null}
    from={{opacity:0}}
    enter={{opacity:1}}
    leave={{opacity:0}}
>
{show => show && (props =>
    <animated.div style={props}>
        //Component content                   
    </animated.div>
)}
</Transition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to see the initail transition you should introduce a flag for it. And based on the flag you can change the from property of the transition. The flag could be either a class variable or a state variable. For example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

initialised = false;

componentDidMount {
  initialised = true;
}

...

<Transition
    native
    items={this.state.showComponent}
    initial={null}
    from={{opacity: this.initialised ? 0 : 1}}
    enter={{opacity:1}}
    leave={{opacity:0}}
>
{show => show && (props =>
    <animated.div style={props}>
        //Component content                   
    </animated.div>
)}
</Transition>
```